# Why are all the homebrew formulas located in the 'libexec' folder?

Tags: homebrew, filesystem

When I install packages manually, the typical layout looks like the following:

```
├── conf
├── lib
├── bin
│   ├── mvn
│   ├── mvn.cmd
```

But when I install it with homebrew, almost all the files are placed in the `libexec` folder:

```
├── bin
│   └── mvn
└── libexec
    ├── bin
    ├── boot
    ├── conf
    └── lib
```

Why is this strange layout used? It's a bit confusing when you read tool's official documentation and your paths mismatch.

Answer (score 13):

The layout was a deliberate design decision on Homebrew’s side to keep the **balance between usability, maintainer sanity, and not breaking things.**

A comment in Homebrew’s [source code](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/aec3d1fe3dd3e7f9de2768af992dbdbb59dc60a5/Library/Homebrew/formula_cellar_checks.rb#L50-L52) says:

> Installing JARs to "lib" can cause conflicts between packages.
>   For Java software, it is typically better for the formula to
>   install to "libexec" and then symlink or wrap binaries into "bin".

Why conflicts?

To explain what the specific conflict is and what causes it, let’s have a look at (a gross simplification of) what Homebrew does when you run `brew install foo`:

1. Homebrew downloads and unpacks everything `foo` needs **according to the formula.**
2. Homebrew follows the installation instruction **according to the formula.** For example, it copies files around, applies patches, and so on. In the end, you get a *keg,* the folder containing the fresh installation.
3. For your convenience, Homebrew looks at the `bin` and `lib` directories of your keg, then symlinks everything it finds into `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib` so you don’t have to.

Note how in #3, the formula **does not have a say.** This helps keep complexity out of the formula definitions. A formula maintainer can never forget to create a symlink because she or he doesn’t have to; Homebrew does it automatically for everything that is in `bin` or `lib`.

The layout policy was (AFAIK) first codified in [issue #678](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/678) of Homebrew’s legacy GitHub repository, which says:

> This is expected behavior; libexec is assumed to be private-use stuff for that formula.

Basically, Homebrew considers the contents of `bin` and `lib` *public* artifacts, i. e. things that are supposed to be called from outside the formula.

Everything else, including the whole content of `libexec`, is considered an implementation detail, i. e. things for private use by the formula itself.

But what is the big deal with that? Could you, as an author of a formula like `maven`, not simply ignore those principles and instead live with a few unnecessary symlinks in `/usr/local/lib`, and give the user the same layout as the upstream project has?

Turns out that yes, you could, but it’s a horrible idea, and **Homebrew maintainers would rightfully refuse such a formula until fixed.**

Publishing private stuff to `/usr/local/lib` is a typical cause of [JAR hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell). (Imagine a Java-based Homebrew formula `foo` which uses `mylib.jar` v1, and another Homebrew formula `bar` which uses `mylib.jar` v2, with the version number not being part of the filename `mylib.jar`. Now go ahead and try to figure out why your business-critical application – which happens to use `/usr/local/lib/mylib.jar` because it’s in the path – only works on that 50% of your machines where `foo` has been installed *after* `bar` but not vice versa. This is an example of the conflict mentioned at the beginning.)

**tl;dr Whatever you put into `lib`, Homebrew will symlink to `/usr/local/lib` for you. Putting a JAR you depend on into `/usr/local/lib` is a bad thing to do and leads to JAR hell.**